# Question about Independent Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $X,Y,Z$ are independent random variables. Then is it true that $X+Y$ and $2Z$ are independent random variables?

I think it is true. Here is a proof sketch of my attempt:

First show that $(X,Y)$ and $Z$ are independent, i.e, $$P\big((X,Y) \in E\;,\; Z \in F\big) = P((X,Y) \in E)\cdot P(Z \in F)$$ for all Borel $E \subset \Bbb R^2$ and $F \subset \Bbb R$. To prove this, fix some Borel $F \subset \Bbb R$, and let $\mathcal{G}_F$ denote the set of all Borel sets $E \subset \Bbb R^2$ such that the above equation holds. By independence of $X,Y,Z$, we know $\mathcal{G}_F$ contains the $\pi$-system consisting of sets of the form $A \times B$, for Borel $A,B \subset \Bbb R$. This $\pi$-system generates the Borel sets on $\Bbb R^2$. It is also easily checked that $\mathcal{G}_F$ forms a Dynkin-system. Thus $\mathcal{G}_F$ consists of all Borel sets in $\Bbb R^2$, so since $F$ was arbitrary it follows that $(X,Y)$ and $Z$ are independent.

Now let $h(x,y) = x+y$ and let $k(z)=2z$. Then $h,k$ are Borel functions on their respective domains, so by independence of $(X,Y)$ and $Z$ it follows that $h(X,Y)$ and $k(Z)$ are independent as well. $\Box$

**Questions:**

1) Is my proof correct, and if so, is it too complicated? Is there a simpler way to show it?

2) More generally, can we show the following? Let $J$ be any set, and $\{X_i\}_{i \in J}$ is a family of random variables indexed by $J$. Suppose that $\Pi$ is a partition of $J$ (i.e, $\Pi$ is a collection of disjoint subsets of $J$ whose union is $J$), and for $I \in \Pi$, define $X_I$ to be the $\Bbb R^I$-valued random variable defined by $X_I(\omega)=(X_i(\omega))_{i \in I}$. Then for any collection of measurable functions $f_I: \Bbb R^I \to \Bbb R$ ($I \in \Pi$), is it true that the family $\{f_I(X_I)\}_{I \in \Pi}$ is an independent collection of random variables?

I think that I have a proof of (2) but it is complicated and possibly wrong...

The above question would be the special case where $J = \{1,2,3\}$, and $\Pi = \big\{\{1,2\},\{3\}\big\}$, with $f_{\{1,2\}}=h$ and $f_{\{3\}} = k$.

Answer (score 0):

It may be best  to formulate this in terms of $\sigma$-algebras. The $\sigma$-algebras $\Sigma_j$ generated by the random variables $X_j$ are independent if and only if the random variables are independent.  Disjoint collections of $j$'s produce independent $\Sigma$-algebras, and random variables that are Borel functions of the corresponding random variables 
are independent.

Comment: You're saying that the $\Sigma_I:=\sigma(\{X_j\}_{j \in I})$ are independent for $I \in \Pi$? I'm not really seeing why that is immediately true. Would I need some lemma to prove that?

Comment: For instance, in the above example, I use the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem to prove that the sigma-algebra generated by $X,Y$ is independent of the one generated by $Z$. Would I do a similar thing for the general case?